How do I get lastlog timestamps in a generic format?
I have multiple Ubuntu machines in different locations. I want to collect the last login information from these machines. However, when I use the lastlog command, it returns dates in different formats.
I wrote a bash script to convert these dates, but when I execute it, it returns an error.
Invalid date 'T3 Thg 6 18 17:33:06 +0700'

convert_to_zulu() {
    local date_string="$1"
    date -d "$date_string" -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
}

lastlog_output=$(lastlog)

echo "Username         Port     From             Latest (Zulu Time)"

echo "$lastlog_output" | while read -r line; do
    # Extract the username and date string
    username=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    port=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    from=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
    date_string=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')

    zulu_date=$(convert_to_zulu "$date_string")
    printf "%-15s %-7s %-15s %s\n" "$username" "$port" "$from" "$zulu_date"
done

Is there any way to convert these dates to a generic standard?

Edit: I have tried the command LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC lastlog and it works as expected.

Command output is often better to put as a plain text instead of unclear picture.

Have you tried something like LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC lastlog? that might save you the trouble of trying to parse and convert the dates altogether

Thanks, Steeldriver. I have tried this and it works fine.

At least in Ubuntu, the lastlog command appears to respect locale and timezone settings.
So instead of trying to parse and convert arbitrary timestamp formats, you could consider setting the lastlog environment to generate a specific format in the first place - for example
LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC lastlog

